# Using SSL to download a file in Android

Tags: android, ssl

Im using this brilliant code snippet to download an XML file:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification

How would I be able to connect via https? I can make the https connection in java but im unsure where to store my certificate file in Android.

Comment: The site you're attempting to has an invalid cert? You shouldn't need to store hte cert in the app otherwise.

Comment: Yes, i have it working in plain java by the following line but cant get it to work in Android: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/web2.uconn.edu.jks");

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do the exact same thing that the code snippet shows you. Just replace HttpURLConnection with [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html).